# unknown string format - Matplotlib plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot stock price data using matplotlib. The data is in txt file(also tried with a csv file). When I run the code I get an error: Unknown string format: %Y-%m-%d.

This is the date format of the data. What am I doing wrong?
below the code:

```
def graphdata(stock):
    try:
        stock_file = stock+'.txt'
        date, openp, highp, lowp, closep, volume = np.loadtxt(stock_file, delimiter=',', unpack=True,
        converters={ 0: mdates.datestr2num('%Y-%m-%d')})

        fig = plt.figure()
        ax1 = plt.sulplot(1,1,1)
        ax1.plot(date, openp)
        ax1.plot(date, highp)
        ax1.plot(date, lowp)
        ax1.plot(date, closep)

        plt.show()
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e), 'failed main loop')


for stock in each_stock:
    graphdata(stock)
    time.sleep(600)
```

For example the data for AAPL looks like this:

4/14/2020   70  72.0625 69.51249695 71.76249695 194994800

4/15/2020   70.59999847 71.58249664 70.15750122 71.10749817 131154400

4/16/2020   71.84500122 72.05000305 70.58750153 71.67250061 157125200

4/17/2020   71.17250061 71.73750305 69.21499634 70.69999695 215250000

4/20/2020   69.48750305 70.41999817 69.21250153 69.23249817 130015200

4/21/2020   69.06999969 69.3125 66.35749817 67.09249878 180991600

Comment: What does the data look like? It will be helpful if we can see the contents of the .csv file, especially the relevant date columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using pandas to read those comma separated files.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def graphdata(stock):
    try:
        stock_file = stock+'.txt'

        df = pd.read_csv(stock_file, header=None, names=['date', 'openp', 'highp', 'lowp', 'closep', 'volume'])

        df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

        df.plot(x='date', y=['openp', 'highp', 'lowp', 'closep'])

        plt.show()

    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e), 'failed main loop')
```

[image]